# Problems with VBoxManage syntax

Tags: cmd, virtualbox

I'm having problems with the syntax in "VBoxManage".
For example: If I want to create and register a virtual machine that is named `"windowsbuffet-311"`, I think it parses like `"windowsbuffet" -311`, and then the entire thing is messed up.
The code that i'm using is below, Please tell me how to fix these errors!

```
vboxmanage createvm "windowsbuffet-311" --register
vboxmanage storagectl "windowsbuffet-311" --name main --add ide --bootable on
vboxmanage storageattach "windowsbuffet-311" --port 1 --device 1 --type hdd --medium "C:\wbft\311\Windows 3.11.vdi" --storagectl main
vboxmanage storageattach "windowsbuffet-311" --type dvddrive --medium none --storagectl main
vboxmanage storagectl "windowsbuffet-311" --name fdd -add floppy
vboxmanage storageattach "windowsbuffet-311" --type fdd -medium none --storagectl fdd
vboxmanage createvm "windowsbuffet-95" --register
vboxmanage storagectl "windowsbuffet-95" --name main --add ide --bootable on
vboxmanage storageattach "windowsbuffet-95" --port 1 --device 1 --type hdd --medium "C:\wbft\95\Windows 95.vdi" --storagectl main
vboxmanage storageattach "windowsbuffet-95" --type dvddrive --medium none --storagectl main
vboxmanage storagectl "windowsbuffet-95" --name fdd -add floppy
vboxmanage storageattach "windowsbuffet-95" --type fdd -medium none --storagectl fdd
vboxmanage createvm "windowsbuffet-2k" --register
vboxmanage storagectl "windowsbuffet-2k" --name main --add ide --bootable on
vboxmanage storageattach "windowsbuffet-2k" --port 1 --device 1 --type hdd --medium "C:\wbft\2000\Windows 2000.vdi" --storagectl main
vboxmanage storageattach "windowsbuffet-2k" --type dvddrive --medium none --storagectl main
vboxmanage storagectl "windowsbuffet-2k" --name fdd -add floppy
vboxmanage storageattach "windowsbuffet-2k" --type fdd -medium none --storagectl fdd
vboxmanage createvm "windowsbuffet-nt4" --register
vboxmanage storagectl "windowsbuffet-nt4" --name main --add ide --bootable on
vboxmanage storageattach "windowsbuffet-nt4" --port 1 --device 1 --type hdd --medium "C:\wbft\nt4\Windows NT 4.vdi" --storagectl main
vboxmanage storageattach "windowsbuffet-nt4" --type dvddrive --medium none --storagectl main
vboxmanage storagectl "windowsbuffet-nt4" --name fdd -add floppy
vboxmanage storageattach "windowsbuffet-nt4" --type fdd -medium none --storagectl fdd
pause
```

And the errors are:

```
Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 4.3.26
(C) 2005-2015 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.

Usage:

VBoxManage createvm         --name <name>
                            [--groups <group>, ...]
                            [--ostype <ostype>]
                            [--register]
                            [--basefolder <path>]
                            [--uuid <uuid>]

VBoxManage.exe: error: Invalid parameter 'windowsbuffet-311'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'windowsbuffet-
311'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), compo
nent VirtualBox, interface IVirtualBox, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(a->argv[0]).raw(), machine.asO
utParam())" at line 1008 of file VBoxManageStorageController.cpp
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'windowsbuffet-
311'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), compo
nent VirtualBox, interface IVirtualBox, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(a->argv[0]).raw(), machine.asO
utParam())" at line 313 of file VBoxManageStorageController.cpp
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'windowsbuffet-
311'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), compo
nent VirtualBox, interface IVirtualBox, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(a->argv[0]).raw(), machine.asO
utParam())" at line 313 of file VBoxManageStorageController.cpp
Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 4.3.26
(C) 2005-2015 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.

Usage:

VBoxManage storagectl       <uuid|vmname>
                            --name <name>
                            [--add ide|sata|scsi|floppy|sas]
                            [--controller LSILogic|LSILogicSAS|BusLogic|
                                          IntelAHCI|PIIX3|PIIX4|ICH6|I82078]
                            [--portcount <1-30>]
                            [--hostiocache on|off]
                            [--bootable on|off]
                            [--remove]

VBoxManage.exe: error: Invalid parameter 'floppy'
Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 4.3.26
(C) 2005-2015 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.

Usage:

VBoxManage storageattach    <uuid|vmname>
                            --storagectl <name>
                            [--port <number>]
                            [--device <number>]
                            [--type dvddrive|hdd|fdd]
                            [--medium none|emptydrive|additions|
                                      <uuid|filename>|host:<drive>|iscsi]
                            [--mtype normal|writethrough|immutable|shareable|
                                     readonly|multiattach]
                            [--comment <text>]
                            [--setuuid <uuid>]
                            [--setparentuuid <uuid>]
                            [--passthrough on|off]
                            [--tempeject on|off]
                            [--nonrotational on|off]
                            [--discard on|off]
                            [--bandwidthgroup <name>]
                            [--forceunmount]
                            [--server <name>|<ip>]
                            [--target <target>]
                            [--tport <port>]
                            [--lun <lun>]
                            [--encodedlun <lun>]
                            [--username <username>]
                            [--password <password>]
                            [--initiator <initiator>]
                            [--intnet]

VBoxManage.exe: error: Invalid parameter 'none'
Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 4.3.26
(C) 2005-2015 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.

Usage:

VBoxManage createvm         --name <name>
                            [--groups <group>, ...]
                            [--ostype <ostype>]
                            [--register]
                            [--basefolder <path>]
                            [--uuid <uuid>]

VBoxManage.exe: error: Invalid parameter 'windowsbuffet-95'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'windowsbuffet-
95'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), compo
nent VirtualBox, interface IVirtualBox, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(a->argv[0]).raw(), machine.asO
utParam())" at line 1008 of file VBoxManageStorageController.cpp
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'windowsbuffet-
95'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), compo
nent VirtualBox, interface IVirtualBox, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(a->argv[0]).raw(), machine.asO
utParam())" at line 313 of file VBoxManageStorageController.cpp
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'windowsbuffet-
95'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), compo
nent VirtualBox, interface IVirtualBox, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(a->argv[0]).raw(), machine.asO
utParam())" at line 313 of file VBoxManageStorageController.cpp
Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 4.3.26
(C) 2005-2015 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.

Usage:

VBoxManage storagectl       <uuid|vmname>
                            --name <name>
                            [--add ide|sata|scsi|floppy|sas]
                            [--controller LSILogic|LSILogicSAS|BusLogic|
                                          IntelAHCI|PIIX3|PIIX4|ICH6|I82078]
                            [--portcount <1-30>]
                            [--hostiocache on|off]
                            [--bootable on|off]
                            [--remove]

VBoxManage.exe: error: Invalid parameter 'floppy'
Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 4.3.26
(C) 2005-2015 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.

Usage:

VBoxManage storageattach    <uuid|vmname>
                            --storagectl <name>
                            [--port <number>]
                            [--device <number>]
                            [--type dvddrive|hdd|fdd]
                            [--medium none|emptydrive|additions|
                                      <uuid|filename>|host:<drive>|iscsi]
                            [--mtype normal|writethrough|immutable|shareable|
                                     readonly|multiattach]
                            [--comment <text>]
                            [--setuuid <uuid>]
                            [--setparentuuid <uuid>]
                            [--passthrough on|off]
                            [--tempeject on|off]
                            [--nonrotational on|off]
                            [--discard on|off]
                            [--bandwidthgroup <name>]
                            [--forceunmount]
                            [--server <name>|<ip>]
                            [--target <target>]
                            [--tport <port>]
                            [--lun <lun>]
                            [--encodedlun <lun>]
                            [--username <username>]
                            [--password <password>]
                            [--initiator <initiator>]
                            [--intnet]

VBoxManage.exe: error: Invalid parameter 'none'
Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 4.3.26
(C) 2005-2015 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.

Usage:

VBoxManage createvm         --name <name>
                            [--groups <group>, ...]
                            [--ostype <ostype>]
                            [--register]
                            [--basefolder <path>]
                            [--uuid <uuid>]

VBoxManage.exe: error: Invalid parameter 'windowsbuffet-2k'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'windowsbuffet-
2k'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), compo
nent VirtualBox, interface IVirtualBox, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(a->argv[0]).raw(), machine.asO
utParam())" at line 1008 of file VBoxManageStorageController.cpp
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'windowsbuffet-
2k'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), compo
nent VirtualBox, interface IVirtualBox, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(a->argv[0]).raw(), machine.asO
utParam())" at line 313 of file VBoxManageStorageController.cpp
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'windowsbuffet-
2k'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), compo
nent VirtualBox, interface IVirtualBox, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(a->argv[0]).raw(), machine.asO
utParam())" at line 313 of file VBoxManageStorageController.cpp
Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 4.3.26
(C) 2005-2015 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.

Usage:

VBoxManage storagectl       <uuid|vmname>
                            --name <name>
                            [--add ide|sata|scsi|floppy|sas]
                            [--controller LSILogic|LSILogicSAS|BusLogic|
                                          IntelAHCI|PIIX3|PIIX4|ICH6|I82078]
                            [--portcount <1-30>]
                            [--hostiocache on|off]
                            [--bootable on|off]
                            [--remove]

VBoxManage.exe: error: Invalid parameter 'floppy'
Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 4.3.26
(C) 2005-2015 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.

Usage:

VBoxManage storageattach    <uuid|vmname>
                            --storagectl <name>
                            [--port <number>]
                            [--device <number>]
                            [--type dvddrive|hdd|fdd]
                            [--medium none|emptydrive|additions|
                                      <uuid|filename>|host:<drive>|iscsi]
                            [--mtype normal|writethrough|immutable|shareable|
                                     readonly|multiattach]
                            [--comment <text>]
                            [--setuuid <uuid>]
                            [--setparentuuid <uuid>]
                            [--passthrough on|off]
                            [--tempeject on|off]
                            [--nonrotational on|off]
                            [--discard on|off]
                            [--bandwidthgroup <name>]
                            [--forceunmount]
                            [--server <name>|<ip>]
                            [--target <target>]
                            [--tport <port>]
                            [--lun <lun>]
                            [--encodedlun <lun>]
                            [--username <username>]
                            [--password <password>]
                            [--initiator <initiator>]
                            [--intnet]

VBoxManage.exe: error: Invalid parameter 'none'
Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 4.3.26
(C) 2005-2015 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.

Usage:

VBoxManage createvm         --name <name>
                            [--groups <group>, ...]
                            [--ostype <ostype>]
                            [--register]
                            [--basefolder <path>]
                            [--uuid <uuid>]

VBoxManage.exe: error: Invalid parameter 'windowsbuffet-nt4'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'windowsbuffet-
nt4'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), compo
nent VirtualBox, interface IVirtualBox, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(a->argv[0]).raw(), machine.asO
utParam())" at line 1008 of file VBoxManageStorageController.cpp
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'windowsbuffet-
nt4'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), compo
nent VirtualBox, interface IVirtualBox, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(a->argv[0]).raw(), machine.asO
utParam())" at line 313 of file VBoxManageStorageController.cpp
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'windowsbuffet-
nt4'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), compo
nent VirtualBox, interface IVirtualBox, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(a->argv[0]).raw(), machine.asO
utParam())" at line 313 of file VBoxManageStorageController.cpp
Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 4.3.26
(C) 2005-2015 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.

Usage:

VBoxManage storagectl       <uuid|vmname>
                            --name <name>
                            [--add ide|sata|scsi|floppy|sas]
                            [--controller LSILogic|LSILogicSAS|BusLogic|
                                          IntelAHCI|PIIX3|PIIX4|ICH6|I82078]
                            [--portcount <1-30>]
                            [--hostiocache on|off]
                            [--bootable on|off]
                            [--remove]

VBoxManage.exe: error: Invalid parameter 'floppy'
Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 4.3.26
(C) 2005-2015 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.

Usage:

VBoxManage storageattach    <uuid|vmname>
                            --storagectl <name>
                            [--port <number>]
                            [--device <number>]
                            [--type dvddrive|hdd|fdd]
                            [--medium none|emptydrive|additions|
                                      <uuid|filename>|host:<drive>|iscsi]
                            [--mtype normal|writethrough|immutable|shareable|
                                     readonly|multiattach]
                            [--comment <text>]
                            [--setuuid <uuid>]
                            [--setparentuuid <uuid>]
                            [--passthrough on|off]
                            [--tempeject on|off]
                            [--nonrotational on|off]
                            [--discard on|off]
                            [--bandwidthgroup <name>]
                            [--forceunmount]
                            [--server <name>|<ip>]
                            [--target <target>]
                            [--tport <port>]
                            [--lun <lun>]
                            [--encodedlun <lun>]
                            [--username <username>]
                            [--password <password>]
                            [--initiator <initiator>]
                            [--intnet]

VBoxManage.exe: error: Invalid parameter 'none'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

On all the lines where you give the createvm command, I think you're missing the "--name" in front of the name of your vm. Try this:

```
vboxmanage createvm --name "windowsbuffet-311" --register
```